# Setting categorical variable as factor influences variable importance table

Tags: r, random-forest, data-preprocessing

I am using caret random forest in R with 20 explanatory variables, some of which are categorical but numerically encoded. For example, one categorical variable is soil drainage with 6 different levels (1 = well-drained, 2 = moderately drained, 3 = poorly drained etc...) Before training and predicting, I set those integer categorical variables to factors. But after running the model, when I viewed the variable importance table each level of those categorical variables is considered (Drainage1, Drainage2...see pic) - which I do not want. Now I am wondering if I should have used one hot encoding instead of as.factor()

[image]

**My question is, if you have a nominal categorical variable class = numeric, should you convert it to a factor OR one hot encode it before using a caret 'rf' random forest model? Or are they both equivalent?**

Comment: A [mcve] (e.g. a data set/model with, say, a single numeric predictor and a single categorical predictor) would be useful to illustrate your point/make it easier for people to explore and answer ...

Comment: I think this will turn out to be *not* about how to specify the model, but about how to make the variable-importance machinery do what you want. A few tests fitting models directly with the `randomForest` package and using the `importance()` function *does* provide a single overall index of variable importance for a factor/categorical predictor ...